# Ruby in Windows CLI, How to do?

Tags: ruby, gcc, command-line-interface

I see in a lot of the tutorials and how to pages, they use the following, or something similar

```
ruby C:\test.rb
```

Which would parse test.rb to the interpreter and ... execute the script. But how is this done on Windows? Ruby isn't a recognized internal command (as per the shell output)?

I know how to do all these things on Linux, and its as simple as... alas Windows is completely confusing at times :)

Comment: Don't confuse DOS with some command-interpreter in Windows. DOS is an OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to add the path to the Ruby executable to your Environment Variables:

1. Right click on 'Computer' in Windows.
2. Click 'Properties...'
3. Select the 'Advanced' tab.
4. Click 'Environment Variables'
5. Find 'Path' in the list and click edit
6. Add `C:\Ruby\bin;` (or wherever you installed Ruby to) to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you could add the directory which contains `ruby.exe` to the System-Variable `Path`, then the above should work. See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for a small tutorial (btw. the directories are separated by `;` (semicolon), not by `:` as in UNIX).

Also possible

```
cd \Path\To\Ruby\Interpreter
ruby.exe C:\test.rb
```

since `.` (the current working directory) is always part of `Path`.